# to display/show vs to be displayed/shown

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

`The user can choose which elements to display/show`

`The user can choose which elements to be displayed/shown`

Which sentence is more correct? Is there any difference when using `show` or `display`.

Comment: Neither is more correct. They are both grammatical. It's a subjective preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the first is correct and the 2nd isn't. If the user is making the choice, then the infinitive would remain active as it refers back to that choice. You could say, The user can choose which elements are displayed/shown, if you want to use passive voice here, as 'elements' then become the subject of the passive verb form.